# Swift: Sort list object by property

Tags: swift, sorting

after a lot of research on the net, I tried several solutions but it does not work? I want to sort my array according to the leaguecode property here is my code:

```
var teams = [Team]()

    dbReference.child(FBDatabaseKeys.teams).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for nameTeam in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value = nameTeam.value as? NSDictionary

            let team = Team(
                capitanId: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.captainID] as! String,
                leagueCode: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.leagueCode] as? String ?? value?["leageCode"] as! String,
                playersIds: [""], //todo retrieve data to array
                teamName: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.teamName] as! String,
                imageUrl: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.imageUrl] as! String,
                groupMoto: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.teamMoto] as! String,
                totalScore: String(format: "%@", value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.totalScore] as? CVarArg ?? "") ,
                totalTickets: String(format: "%@", value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.totalTickets] as? CVarArg ?? "")
            )

            if team.leagueCode == self.currentPlayer.leagueCode{
                teams.append(team)
            }
        }

        teams = teams.sort {
            Int($0.leagueCode)! < Int($1.leagueCode)!
        } as! [Team]

        //Sort array by property score
        completion(teams)
    }
```

**Error**:

> Error:(204, 27) cannot assign value of type '()' to type '[Team]'

Here is my object:

```
struct Team {
let capitanId: String
let leagueCode: String
let playersIds: [String]
let teamName: String
let imageUrl: String
let groupMoto: String
let totalScore: String
let totalTickets: String
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you want to sort by both league code and total score?

Comment: No only league code I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

> cannot assign value of type '()'

clearly says that the `sort` function doesn't return anything. The array is sorted in place.

And the conversions to `Int` are not necessary. You can sort strings numerically with `localizedStandardCompare`

```
teams.sort {
    $0.leagueCode.localizedStandardCompare($1.leagueCode) == .orderedAscending
}
```

Comment: let sortedTeam = teams.sort {
                $0.totalScore.localizedStandardCompare($1.totalScore) == .orderedAscending
            }

            //Sort array by property score
            completion(sortedTeam)

Comment: error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[Team]'

Comment: No, **not** `let sortedTeams = ...`. Please read me answer carefully (***The array is sorted in place***). If you want to assign the result to a new variable you have to use `sorted` (with trailing **ed**)

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
teams  = teams.sorted {
  Int($0.leagueCode)! < Int($1.leagueCode)!
}
```

Or only `mutating`

```
teams.sort {
    Int($0.leagueCode)! < Int($1.leagueCode)!
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296801-sort

//

```
dbReference.child(FBDatabaseKeys.teams).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for nameTeam in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let value = nameTeam.value as? NSDictionary

            let team = Team(
                capitanId: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.captainID] as! String,
                leagueCode: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.leagueCode] as? String ?? value?["leageCode"] as! String,
                playersIds: [""], //todo retrieve data to array
                teamName: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.teamName] as! String,
                imageUrl: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.imageUrl] as! String,
                groupMoto: value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.teamMoto] as! String,
                totalScore: String(format: "%@", value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.totalScore] as? CVarArg ?? "") ,
                totalTickets: String(format: "%@", value?[FBDatabaseKeys.Teams.totalTickets] as? CVarArg ?? "")
            )

            if team.leagueCode == self.currentPlayer.leagueCode{
                teams.append(team)
            }
        }

        teams.sort {
            Int($0.leagueCode)! < Int($1.leagueCode)!
        }  


        completion(teams)
}
```

Comment: error: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type '[Team]